# array_shift causes php to silently crash

Tags: php

I have this small snippet of code:

```
echo '<br>T COUNT '.count($tokens);

echo '<br>ARRAY COUNT '.count($tokens);
while (count($tokens)) {
  echo '<br>I GET HERE';
  echo '<pre>'.print_r($tokens,true).'</pre>';
  $token = array_shift($tokens);
  echo '<br>BUT NOT HERE '.$token;
  ...
}
```

which is causing PHP to silently crash, and its got me completely stumped. In the output, below, you can see that it executes up through the print_r, but does not reach the echo statement right after array_shift, and you can also see that the $tokens variable print_r's as an 'array' (and a small array at that -- should be quite manageable). I've even tried putting a try/catch around the array_shift and putting a debug output in the catch, but nothing is printed.

```
ARRAY COUNT 1

I GET HERE

Array (
    [0] => SassScriptFunction Object
        (
            [name:SassScriptFunction:private] => rgb
            [args:SassScriptFunction:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SassNumber Object
                        (
                            [numeratorUnits:SassNumber:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [denominatorUnits:SassNumber:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [inExpression] => 1
                            [value] => 0
                            [units] => 
                        )

                    [1] => SassNumber Object
                        (
                            [numeratorUnits:SassNumber:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [denominatorUnits:SassNumber:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [inExpression] => 1
                            [value] => 0
                            [units] => 
                        )

                    [2] => SassNumber Object
                        (
                            [numeratorUnits:SassNumber:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [denominatorUnits:SassNumber:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [inExpression] => 1
                            [value] => 0
                            [units] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Do you have proper error reporting enabled? I [cannot reproduce](http://codepad.org/qFlAqHg7) the error, so either something is wrong with your whole PHP or another part of the code

Comment: I have yet to see php "silently" crash without someone surpressing an error or disabling all error logging/reporting. Check your error log and add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to the top of your script.

Comment: Just a side note: why don't you run `count($tokens)` once and assign it to a variable? Cut yourself out some overhead since you call `count()` 3 times in your snippet

Comment: I believe error reporting is on; display_errors is set to 'On' and error_reporting is E_ALL, and error_log to  /var/log/php.error, which are all reflected in my phpinfo(); output.

Comment: @Darren, I just tried putting the count() in a variable then using for() to try and iterate through the array. The script still dies upon trying to access the first element of the array. It's almost as if there's a SEGFAULT.

Comment: Array Count 1,  your $tokens array has only one element and array_shift maybe you re looking for count($tokens[0]) ?

Comment: @DrSpy, I believe its correct as-is, I am actually trying to debug a CMS plugin that used to work on earlier versions of the CMS, but has broken since. The first time this function is called just so happens to be an array of one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite sure array_shift is not the problem.

Line

```
echo '<br>BUT NOT HERE '.$token;
```

is, as you use object as string.

Try using

```
echo '<br>BUT NOT HERE '.print_r($token,true);
```

Comment: Damn, yeah that was it! Now I feel silly. No idea why php wasn't throwing an Object to String Exception though...

Comment: I thought it was that at first, but when i ran the OP's example it worked perfectly so I overlooked it. Good pick up mleko!!

Comment: There is no such exception. But there is error: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class XXX could not be converted to string

Comment: Oh okay, I've seen Array to String exceptions in my debugging today, so thought there'd be something analogous for objects. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since `array_shift()` can handle an array by reference, you could easily try something like this:

```
$tokens = [
    '32h',
    '235hg',
    'sdfdsdngdfngdf',
    'sfngfsnn',
    'sfngsfn',
    'sfnsgfnnfsnbsfgn',
    'fsnfgsng',
    'sfgnsfgn'
];

$count = count($tokens);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo '<br>I GET HERE';
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($tokens, true) . '</pre>';
    array_shift($tokens);
}
```

<sup>*I don't know what your `$tokens` array looks like, so I made up a random one.*</sup>

The above example works flawlessly as expected.

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/232710)

The only other suggestion is (as said in the comments), to turn on error reporting.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

---

Also, as stated, we don't know what `$tokens` looks like. Could you please supply an example, since that might be your issue. (The count being 1 as [@DrSpy Stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390673/array-shift-causes-php-to-silently-crash#comment43229983_27390673))

Comment: Interesting enough, looping through the array with for() then assigning the value still fails, however foreach seems to function until something else tries to access it. The array is an array of objects (in this case 'SassScriptFunction') -- I wish I knew more about this object I am actually trying to debug a CMS plugin. Looking at the array's print_r in my output above I see there are a lot of private fields in that object. Could that be relevant?

Comment: What do you mean assigning it? Are you trying to do something like `$token = array_shift($tokens);` ? Try implement what I supplied above and see if that makes a difference? Btw what CMS is it? (Could possibly be a cache issue on your code ;))

Comment: The code you implemented does indeed work. By assigning it I mean if I loop through with a for($i=0;$i<count($tokens);$i++), it fails when inside the loop I try to do $token = $tokens[$i], which suggests that the failure isn't necessarily related to array_shift, but accessing the data inside that first element. Would somehow the data in the element cause it to fail? The CMS is Statamic

Comment: Hmm, that's a good thought, but I don't think its caching in this instance b/c I have it in dev mode, and I've been adding in debug outputs all day trying to figure it out and have had them showing up every time I make a change.

Comment: Hrm that is a weird situation. What happens if you try using `unset($tokens[0]); $tokens = array_values($tokens);` ?

Comment: After running those two lines of code, $tokens is just an empty array (which I think would be the expected output?)

Comment: It should eventually turn out to be an empty array, since `array_shift()` removes the first element of the array, so if it prints sort of like the example I posted, then it should be correct. depending on how many items you have in the array.

Comment: I think @mleko actually just nailed it -- it was my actual debug output that was causing it to crash because the element in the array was an object and I was trying to concatenate it to my output without doing print_r. No idea why php wasn't throwing an Object to String Exception though... Thanks for your help!